# Postgresql date interval and SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql

I use portgres
I have this query which is running successful.

```
SELECT count(distinct(salary.id)) AS nbr
FROM salary salary  
 WHERE  salary.status ='P'

 AND (salary.date_jc_salary is NULL  and case priority_salary  
 WHEN 'N' THEN current_date > date_send_salary +interval '36'  hour  
 WHEN 'U'  THEN current_date > date_send_salary +interval '24'  hour 
 ELSE current_date > date_send_salary +interval '36'  hour end 
 OR (salary.date_jc_salary is NOT NULL 
 AND to_char(current_date , 'yyyy/MM/dd') >= to_char(date_jc_salary , 'yyyy/MM/dd')

 ) )
```

my problem that I want to make subquery to have the value of interval.

meaning make this query :

```
SELECT count(distinct(salary.id)) AS nbr
FROM salary salary  
 WHERE  salary.status ='P'

 AND (salary.date_jc_salary is NULL  and case priority_salary  
 WHEN 'N' THEN current_date > date_send_salary +interval '36'  hour  
 WHEN 'U'  THEN current_date > date_send_salary +interval '24'  hour 
 ELSE current_date > date_send_salary +interval '36'  hour end 
 OR (salary.date_jc_salary is NOT NULL 
and current_date > salary.date_jc_salary +interval select salary.date_jc_salary::date - now()::date  day  
 ) )
```

so change only this line :

```
and current_date > salary.date_jc_salary +interval select salary.date_jc_salary::date - now()::date  day
```

but I have this error :

```
  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 10: ...rrent_date > salary.date_jc_salary  -interval select sal...
                                                              ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 847
```

the goal is to add to the date **date_jc_salary**  a number of day which is the difference between **date_jc_salary**  and **current date**

Comment: Try with this: `and current_date > salary.date_jc_salary + (select salary.date_jc_salary::date - now()::date)`

Comment: thank you for your response, the problem is solved now